# WindowsApp AppWindow content

Tags: c#, .net-core, winui-3, .net-7.0, windows-app-sdk

Windows 11
VS2022
WinUI3 Desktop WindowsAppSDK 1.2.230
.Net core 7

I'm creating a desktop app using MVPVM design principles. The documentation says that Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window used within a UWP is not longer available, and is switching to Microsoft.UI.Windowsing.AppWindow.

I'm trying to add some page navigation and page content to the AppWindow. The AccountLinkView never displays.
This is within the App.xaml.cs (which works fine) but I feel like I'm missing something.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        new MainWindow().Activate();
        if (e != null)
        {
            AppWindow rootWindow = WindowPresenter.Window;
            if (rootWindow == null)
            {
                WindowPresenter.Initialize();
                WindowPresenter.Navigate(typeof(AccountLinkView));
            }
            WindowPresenter.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this Contributor's answer in Github https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6755

> In Windows AppSDK, the `AppWindow` class doesn't own and manage its
> own window, but represents an existing window that already has content
> that was drawn using a UI framework.

So, you can not use `AppWindow` to navigate pages or windows.

You can set the page navigation and page content [in the MainWindow with Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.frame?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2#examples).

```
 protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    m_window = new MainWindow();

    Frame rootFrame = new Frame();
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(AccountLinkView));

    m_window.Content = rootFrame;
    m_window.Activate();
}
```

Comment: Ok the problem I had with this before getting to where I am now, was the 

Frame rootFrame=Window.Current.Content as Frame;

kept raising a NullReferenceException from Window. Window was null.

Comment: I modified my answer, hope it helps you.